# How to update data on the screen without printing a new line in *nix or Perl?

Tags: linux, perl, unix

Here what I would like the output to show:

`_______ of __________ total files, __________% complete`

I have the capability to update all of these individual values (i.e. the '_'s), but I would like to ONLY update the value, rather than printing a new line every time.  Is this a possibility?

Comment: Put `\r` at the end of your line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
perl -e '$i=0;$|=1;while (1) { sleep 1; print $i++ . " of 199990 files \r"; }'
```

Or use a Curses module

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Curses module - [curses UI](http://search.cpan.org/~mdxi/Curses-UI-0.9609/lib/Curses/UI.pm) It allows you to work with terminal the you need (and much more). It might be a little tough to get your head around it at the beginning, you might want to look at these [examples](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/MDXI/Curses-UI-0.9609/examples/demo-widgets)

Answer (score 0):

You could use [ANSI escape sequence](http://www.bashguru.com/2010/04/how-to-handle-cursor-movement-in-shell.html) to print your new line on top of the last one.

This is an easy and simple solution preventing from spamming your screen.